# Can I use Perl in vim with only the Perl dll on my system?

Tags: perl, vim

I would like to use Perl from within vim (via perldo).

I use vim 7.3 on Windows, compiled with `+perl/dyn` and `-DDYNAMIC_PERL_DLL="perl512.dll"`.

I don't have Perl installed on my system, however I do have perl512.dll in my vim runtimepath, but this doesn't seem to work, `has('perl')` echoes 0. I also tried placing the dll on the system path with the same result.

Is the dll sufficient to get it to work or do I need to have a full install of Perl?

Comment: Maybe, depending on your use of perl, use [TinyPerl](http://tinyperl.sf.net)?

Comment: My vim version was compiled with perl512.dll (which I got from the regular Perl distribution). TinyPerl seems to use a newer version of Perl (perl 58) so it wouldn't work with my vim version. Anyway, what I would like to know is if using the dll instead of the fully installed version of Perl is enough for vim-perl. Here it's suggested that it would be enough (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Perl_compatible_regular_expressions) but it doesen't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perl512.dll` is depend on `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll`.
Then if you want to enable perl without `perl.exe`, you should copy `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll` also. I could get has("perl") == 1 without `perl.exe`.
But I don't comment the way. :)

Comment: that worked, but it only provides some features. it will complain about missing libraries when trying to use some stuff. I tried doing a substitute with `\p{L}` as my search pattern and it complained about missing utf8.pm, but hey, it works for the basic stuff... so thanks for the answer.